# Salesforce Event updates parent record (Apex After Insert Trigger)

Tags: salesforce

I have a basic trigger below that should update the field, Last Meeting Date, after saving a new event. The code works fine in my Sandbox environment, however it shows 0% code coverage and will not allow me to roll out into production. Any help would be appreciated.

```
trigger createLastReviewDate on Event (after insert) {

//map object to store account id and task create date
Map<Id,Date> accIds = new Map<Id,Date>();

//iterate over the new triggers and get the account id and task create date
    for(Event e : trigger.new){
    accIds.put(e.AccountId,Date.valueOf(e.StartDateTime));
    }

//get the accounts to be updated
    List<Account> acctsToUpdate = [Select Id,Last_Meeting_Date__c from     Account where id in:accIds.keySet()];

//update the custom date field
    for(Account acc : acctsToUpdate){
     acc.Last_Meeting_Date__c = accIds.get(acc.Id);
    }
update acctsToUpdate;   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce has a built-in control that requires that all Apex code - Classes, Triggers, etc - include Unit Test classes.  In order to promote code from a sandbox to Production, your code base must include 75% code coverage - calculated by line coverage.

Often times, developing good test classes/methods can take more time that writing the actual code.  This is because you should include positive and negative tests and need to take the time to actually build your test data.

Please review the Salesforce Developer Guide for information about how to develop test classes and Salesforce's testing best practices: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_best_practices.htm  Developing good habits around Unit Testing is critical to becoming a good developer.  Half of my interview questions are based around testing - if you can write good test code, you can write good code.

Answer (score 0):

> Do you have test class written? If so please share it.

Your Trigger is simple and should not create issues for you.

All you need is 1% code coverage on Apex Triggers to deploy. Overall Code Coverage of 75% is must for Classes.

Comment: I figured this was a simple trigger and grew concerned when there was an issue migrating from sandbox to production. At this time there is no test class written, mainly because I was unaware that was a requirement.